# Clojurescript Array-Map order

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

How can I keep order in array-map? Array-map with a length above 8 behaves completely different in Clojure and Clojurescript. Example:

cljs

```
(array-map :a true :c true :d false :b true :z false :h false
           :o true :p true :w false :r true :t false :g false)
-> {:o true, :p true, :r true, :t false, :w false, :z false, :a true, :b true, :c true, :d false, :g false, :h false}
```

clj

```
(array-map :a true :c true :d false :b true :z false :h false
           :o true :p true :w false :r true :t false :g false)
-> {:a true :c true :d false :b true :z false :h false :o true :p true :w false :r true :t false :g false}
```

Comment: I suspect ClojureScript is not creating an array-map. What is its `type`? This could happen if it creates an empty array-map, into which it `assoc`s or `conj`s new entries. At some stage, it will flip into a hash-map. This could be considered a bug, I think. The official docs promise you an array-map.

Answer (score 2):

*Update:*

As of release 2371, non-higher-order calls to `cljs.core/array-map` are backed by a macro which emits hash maps for > 8 key-value pairs. See [CLJS-873](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-873) for ticket + patch.

---

*(Original answer follows.)*

The most likely explanation is that you're doing this at the REPL. ClojureScript's standard REPL, as implemented in the (Clojure) namespace `cljs.repl`, operates by receiving string representations of returned values from the JS environment, reading them to produce Clojure data and printing them back out again. See [line 156 of src/clj/cljs/repl.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/r2371/src/clj/cljs/repl.clj#L156) in ClojureScript's sources (link to release 2371).

When the return value of an expression entered on the REPL is a large array map – or a sorted map, or a [data.avl](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl) sorted map – reading its string representation will produce a hash map on the Clojure side. Needless to say, when this hash map is then printed, the original ordering is lost.

To confirm whether this is indeed what is happening, try doing this at the REPL (copied & pasted from a ClojureScript REPL session in a current checkout):

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (array-map 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
{1 2, 3 4, 5 6, 7 8, 9 10, 11 12, 13 14}
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (array-map 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18)
{7 8, 1 2, 15 16, 13 14, 17 18, 3 4, 11 12, 9 10, 5 6}
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (seq (array-map 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18))
([1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8] [9 10] [11 12] [13 14] [15 16] [17 18])
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (hash-map 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18)
{7 8, 1 2, 15 16, 13 14, 17 18, 3 4, 11 12, 9 10, 5 6}
```

Note that calling `seq` on your array map does produce the expected result.

Comment: I created a ticket in JIRA to track this: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-872. It's a minor issue, but still worth ironing out eventually, I guess.

Comment: It's probably not a problem only with the REPL. Your code is returned well, even without the use of "seq". In contrast, my array-map "seq" does not help at all. As I understand it, if it's a problem with the REPL, this iteration should work correctly, but does not work.

`(for [[k v] (array-map :a true :c true :d false :b true :z false :h false
                      :o true :p true :w false :r true :t false :g false)]
  [k v])`

Comment: You're right – there's a bug in how non-higher-order calls to `cljs.core/array-map` are handled. I submitted a ticket with patch @ http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-873.

Comment: A quick update: my patch has been merged to master, `array-map` should behave as expected in the next release.

Comment: Hey Michal, has this issue been fixed? because I still get this

`(println (array-map :one 1 :two 2 :three 3 :four 4 :five 5 :six 6 :seven 7 :eight 8 :nine 9))`

Returns this unordered map `{:one 1, :eight 8, :three 3, :five 5, :four 4, :nine 9, :two 2, :seven 7, :six 6}`

Comment: @HenryZhu Yes, my patch has been merged to master as mentioned above – see the link to the ticket in the answer – and we've had a number of releases since then. The earliest release to include the patch is 2411. Also, I pasted your example into a REPL running ClojureScript master just now and got the expected result (= insertion ordering preserved). The "P" in "REPL" still treats ordered collections as unordered for reasons explained in the answer; I created [CLJS-872](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-872) to track this issue, but I think it's much lower priority than the CLJS-873 bug.