# ClojureScript array-map and sorted-map-by bug?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

```
(let [mymap (into {} (for [x (shuffle (rest (clojure.string/split "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" #"")))]
                       {x {:idx (rand-int 24)}}))]
  (into (sorted-map-by (fn [k1 k2]
                         (compare [(get-in mymap [k1 :idx]) k1]
                                  [(get-in mymap [k2 :idx]) k2])))
        mymap))
```

or

```
(let [mymap (into {} (for [x (shuffle (rest (clojure.string/split "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" #"")))]
                       {x {:idx (rand-int 24)}}))]
  (->> mymap
       (sort-by (fn [[_ m]] (:idx m)))
       (into (array-map))))
```

=> {"d" {:idx 22}, "n" {:idx 22}, "z" {:idx 14}, "w" {:idx 11}, "s" {:idx 17}, "f" {:idx 20}, "e" {:idx 19}, "q" {:idx 12}, "p" {:idx 10}, "j" {:idx 0}, "x" {:idx 20}, "v" {:idx 14}, "a" {:idx 1}, "t" {:idx 13}, "i" {:idx 21}, "k" {:idx 16}, "b" {:idx 23}, "r" {:idx 3}, "y" {:idx 18}, "g" {:idx 0}, "l" {:idx 16}, "u" {:idx 20}, "h" {:idx 10}, "m" {:idx 16}, "o" {:idx 11}, "c" {:idx 4}}

If we limit the amount to 8 is ok.

```
(let [mymap (into {} (for [x (shuffle (rest (clojure.string/split "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" #"")))]
                       {x (rand-int 24)}))]
  (into (sorted-map-by (fn [k1 k2]
                         (compare [(get mymap k1) k1]
                                  [(get mymap k2) k2])))
        (take 8 mymap)))
```

{"z" {:idx 1}, "q" {:idx 6}, "n" {:idx 7}, "s" {:idx 7}, "f" {:idx 9}, "d" {:idx 17}, "w" {:idx 18}, "e" {:idx 21}}

may be associated with [Clojurescript Array-Map order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349324/clojurescript-array-map-order)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is one big question.

Answer (score 2):

What version of clojurescript are you using? The first form in cljs 0.0-3308 keeps the sort order as you expect:

```
    (println *clojurescript-version*) ;=>  "0.0-3308"

    (let [mymap (into {} (for [x (shuffle (rest (clojure.string/split "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" #"")))]
                           {x {:idx (rand-int 24)}}))]
      (into (sorted-map-by (fn [k1 k2]
                             (compare [(get-in mymap [k1 :idx]) k1]
                                      [(get-in mymap [k2 :idx]) k2])))
            mymap))
    ;=> {"d" {:idx 0}, "i" {:idx 0}, "w" {:idx 5}, "n" {:idx 6}, "q" {:idx 9}, "y" {:idx 9}, "k" {:idx 10}, "m" {:idx 10}, "x" {:idx 10}, "c" {:idx 12}, "h" {:idx 12}, "l" {:idx 13}, "v" {:idx 14}, "s" {:idx 15}, "z" {:idx 16}, "j" {:idx 17}, "p" {:idx 17}, "t" {:idx 17}, "o" {:idx 18}, "r" {:idx 19}, "b" {:idx 20}, "e" {:idx 20}, "a" {:idx 21}, "f" {:idx 21}, "g" {:idx 22}, "u" {:idx 23}}
```

Are you using a **version older than 2411**? That's the first release that includes the fix for the issue explained in the answer to the question you linked. It was fixed on [this commit](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/d374201cb96c6a79c5f469170f81ec3aa8d41aa6) which was first released in version 2411.